# selenium iframe element not found

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate logging into http://wallethub.com/ using selenium java code.
After clicking on Sign in link, a modal popup comes up with an iframe containing username and password fields, however I am not able to find the username field using following selenium code.

```
WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
d.get("http://wallethub.com/profile/test_insurance_company/");
WebElement signIn = d.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In"));
signIn.click();

WebElement frame = d.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));

WebDriver.TargetLocator locator =  d.switchTo();
WebDriver frameDriver = locator.frame(frame);
WebElement active = locator.activeElement();
frameDriver.findElement(By.id("overlay-username")).sendKeys(user);
```

My code dies on the last line saying cannot find "overlay-username" field, however I have verified , this field exists in firebug console.

This is on linux.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct `iframe`? Common mistake I make when I just inspect the element and follow the breadcrumbs and don't bother looking at the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Keikoku assumed you are working with the wrong iframe. There is also GoogleTagManger included in the page. If you check `frame.getAttribute("src")` you'll see `https://apis.google.com/...`.

You can select the correct IFrame with this selector:

```
frame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#wh-overlay-frame-inside iframe"));
```